# How to show only the above the price of average Prices?

Tags: sorting, ms-access, filter, average

I am stuck at a problem where I don't understand how to filter all the prices that are above average. Here is a picture of the names and prices:

[image]

I believe that I have to do this in the Design View, but I have no clue on how to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *DAvg* in your query:

```sql
SELECT 
    Products.[Product Name], 
    Products.[List Price]
FROM 
    Products
WHERE 
    Products.[List Price] > DAvg("[List Price]","[Products]");
```